# Where are lower_bound and upper_bound on get_table_row on nodeos 1.6+ rpc api?

Tags: rpc

I noticed that the lower_bound and upper_bound parameters do not exist anymore after the nodeos 1.6 version on the RPC api.

```
https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/v1.7.0/reference#get_table_rows
https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/v1.5.0/reference#get_table_rows
```

How can I get a subset of my elements using my primary index?

Answer (score 2):

It was an error in the documentation. lower_bound and upper_bound do exist in the source code:

```
struct get_table_rows_params {
  bool        json = false;
  name        code;
  string      scope;
  name        table;
  string      table_key;
  string      lower_bound;
  string      upper_bound;
  uint32_t    limit = 10;
  string      key_type;  // type of key specified by index_position
  string      index_position; // 1 - primary (first), 2 - secondary index (in order defined by multi_index), 3 - third index, etc
  string      encode_type{"dec"}; //dec, hex , default=dec
  optional<bool>  reverse;
  optional<bool>  show_payer; // show RAM pyer
};
```

https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/v1.7.4/plugins/chain_plugin/include/eosio/chain_plugin/chain_plugin.hpp